# DB2 ALTER TABLE QUERY NOT SUPPORTING INSIDE STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, alter-table

I am trying to run below stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATAMART.UPDATE_IDENTITY()
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONST_MESSAGE_ENTRY_KEY INTEGER;

    SET CONST_MESSAGE_ENTRY_KEY = (SELECT MAX(MESSAGE_ENTRY_KEY) FROM DATAMART.MESSAGE_ENTRIES_LOG);

    ALTER TABLE DATAMART.MESSAGE_ENTRIES_LOG ALTER COLUMN MESSAGE_ENTRY_KEY RESTART WITH CONST_MESSAGE_ENTRY_KEY;   
    
END;
```

I am getting this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "ALTER" was found following "E_ENTRIES_LOG)".  Expected tokens may include:  "
>
> ".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Note: if I run alter query without stored procedure, it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is the documented behaviour.

ALTER (as a static statement) is not supported in compound SQL (compiled) blocks, for Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows.

See documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html).

If you want to run an ALTER statement inside an SQL PL stored procedure, you must use dynamic SQL  (i.e. `prepare & execute` , or `execute immediate` ), and obey all the other documented rules.